# Angular firestore get a document without subscribing

Tags: angularfire2

How to fetch a document from firestore without subscribing. I achieved with the below code which first subscribes, fetches the users and then unsubscribes. Is there a simple get method as in SQL. 
Here 'email' is a field in documents.

```
 usercollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;

 fellowuser: Observable<User[]>;

 fellowsubscription: Subscription;
 ......
 this.usercollection = this.angularfirestore.collection ('users', ref => { 

    return ref.where ('email','==','user@example.com');

  });

  this.fellowuser = this.usercollection.valueChanges ();

  this.fellowsubscription = this.fellowuser.subscribe (

    (users) => {

      console.log ( users );

      this.fellowsubscription.unsubscribe ();
    }
  )
```

email is unique for a document. Document ID is not known.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the take(1) operator to kill the subscription. For example:

```
  this.angularfirestore.collection('users').valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(res => {

  console.log(res); //Use the returned data as you normally would

});
```

Make sure to import

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```